# Recorrer un ResultSet de objetos que tienen otro objeto como atributo

Tags: java, base-de-datos, sql

El problema se encuentra en que creo objetos de clase Coche que tienen como atributo un objeto de clase Motor, al recorrer el `resulSet` de la `query` he imprimir los datos no consigo hacerlo bien.

En la base de datos hay guardados **2 coches y 2 motores** que tienen como fk la id de uno de los coches, A la hora de imprimir el resultado me imprime lo siguiente:

```
selectSQL= "SELECT * FROM COCHE,MOTOR";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo se aprecia en la imagen se ve como imprime dos veces el coche 1, una con su motor y otra con el otro, lo mismo ocurre con el coche 2.

Adjunto el código

```
    private void lecturaBDSQL(){
    conexion.getConexion();
    stm = conexion.getStatement();   
    selectSQL= "SELECT * FROM COCHE,MOTOR";
    //selectMotor="SELECT * FROM MOTOR";
    //selectMotor= "SELECT * FROM MOTOR";
  //Debuggin correcto
    try {
       rs = stm.executeQuery(selectSQL);
      //  rsMotor = stm.executeQuery(selectMotor);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al lanzar la query para recuperar los datos de la tabla COCHES");
    }
    try{

            while(rs.next()){
                       System.out.println("*****************************************");
                       System.out.println("El id del coche es: "+rs.getInt(1));
                       System.out.println("La marca del coche es: "+rs.getString(2));
                       System.out.println("El modelo del coche es: "+rs.getString(3));
                       System.out.println("El numero de plazas del coche es: "+rs.getInt(4));
                       System.out.println("El precio final del coche es: "+rs.getInt(5)+"\n");

                       System.out.println("El carburante que usa el motor es: "+rs.getString(6));
                       System.out.println("La potencia del motor es de: "+rs.getInt(7)+" CV");
                       System.out.println("La cilindrada del motor es de: "+rs.getInt(8)+" cm3");
                       System.out.println("El numero de cilindros del motor es  "+rs.getInt(9)+"\n");
                       System.out.println("***************************************** \n \n \n");
                   }


    }catch(Exception recorrido){
        System.out.println("Error al recorrer el resultSet que contiene la informacion de la table COCHE");
        try {
            stm.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al intentar cerrar la conexion con la BD SQL. \n");
        }

        try{

        rs=stm.executeQuery(selectMotor);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
             System.out.println("Error al lanzar la query para recuperar los datos de la tabla COCHES");
         }


        conexion.cerrarConexion();
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Un coche puede tener un solo motor pero la consulta que haces esta buscándote dentro de la tabla `MOTOR` todos los datos al mismo tiempo que `COCHE`. Creo que necesitas un `JOIN`. Sería algo como `select * from COCHE join COCHE.id on MOTOR.id`

Comment: Pensaba que el FROM COCHE,MOTOR actuaba como join.

Comment: Que motor de BD estas usando?

Comment: Oracle - SQL Developer

Comment: Es como dice @Angel la solución esta en cambiar tu query.

Comment: Tenía razón todo perfecto, ahora funciona como debería, lo gracioso es que hace horas probé con el join y no me funcionó, supongo que habría algun error de sintaxis que se me pasó. Muchas gracias

Comment: Invito a @Angel a que ponga su comentario como respuesta, la des por valida y cerrar la pregunta. Saludos y exitos!

Comment: @Rostan Listo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Un coche puede tener un solo motor pero la consulta que haces esta buscándote dentro de la tabla `MOTOR` todos los datos al mismo tiempo que `COCHE`. Creo que necesitas un `JOIN`. Sería algo como

`select * from COCHE join COCHE.id on MOTOR.id`